# When Modeling Cox Spatial point process, for example thomas, LGCP, MatClust,and so on, how can I validate the model fitted?

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

```
library(spatstat)

# Definir a janela espacial
Window <- owin(c(0, 10), c(0, 10))

# Definir uma função de intensidade espacial
intensity_function <- function(x, y) {
  # Intensidade aumenta com a distância da origem
  intensity <- 1 + 0.2 * sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
  return(intensity)
}

# Gerar um processo de Poisson não homogêneo
process <- rpoispp(intensity_function, win=Window)

# Plotar o processo
fit <- kppm(process, ~1,"Thomas")    
fit1 <- kppm(process, ~1,"MatClust")  
fit2 <- kppm(process, ~1,"LGCP")
```

> I trued to use AIC, but they returned errors, I trued to test residuals, but the function diagnose isn´t available, I trued qqplot but also returned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to do *both* **model selection** (using tools like AIC or `anova`) and **model validation** (using residuals and diagnostics).

For **model selection**:

> I tried to use AIC, but they returned errors

(*Tip*: When posting a question, please include the commands that you typed and the error message that was returned.)

Presumably the command you typed was `AIC(fit)`. When I try this, the error message says

> Error: logLik is only available for kppm objects fitted with method='palm' or method='clik2'

That suggests that, in the calls to `kppm`, you should have set `method='palm'` or `method='clik2'`.

If you type `traceback()` immediately after the error message, the nested sequence of function calls is printed. We can see that the command `AIC(fit)` is dispatched to the method `AIC.kppm`. The help file for `AIC.kppm` specifically mentions that

> These methods apply only when the model was fitted by maximising a
> composite likelihood: either the Palm likelihood (Tanaka et al,
> 2008) or the second order composite likelihood (Guan, 2006), by
> calling ‘kppm’ with the argument ‘method="palm"’ or
> ‘method="clik2"’ respectively.

So, the way to get AIC values for fitted models is to fit the models using the argument `method="palm"` or `method="clik2"`. Example:

```
fitT <- kppm(redwood ~ 1, "Thomas", method="p")
AIC(fitT)
```

You will also be able to do things like `anova` to compare two models when one is a special case of the other.

For **model validation**, I'm afraid that the available tools are limited for `kppm` objects. You can use

```
diagnose.ppm(as.ppm(fitT), compute.sd=FALSE)
```

to get the standard informal diagnostics for the trend component, ignoring the clustering component. Informal validation of fitted cluster process models is still a research area.

By the way, `diagnose` is not a defined generic in `spatstat`, so `diagnose(fitT)` does not work.